# How to fix the error "Property contains doesnt exist on type 'RefObject' using typescript and react?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

i want to close the dialog on user clicking anywhere outside the dialog using typescript and react.

below is my code,

```
function Dialog ({setIsDialogOpen, items}: Props) {
    const dialogRef = React.useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);


    React.useEffect(() => {
        const handleClickOutsideDialog = (event: any) => {
            if (
                dialogRef &&
                    !dialogRef.contains(event.target)//error here
            ) {
                alert('You clicked outside of me!');
                setIsDialogOpen(false);
              }
        };
        document.addEventListener('mousedown', handleClickOutsideDialog);
    }, [setIsDialogOpen]);


    return (
        <Wrapper ref={dialogRef}>
            <Container_one>
                <span>title</span>
                <Description> some big description</Description>
            </Container_one>
            <Container_two>
                {items.map(item => (
                    <div
                        key={item.id}
                    />
                ))}
            </Container_two>
        </Wrapper>
    );
```

I am not sure what is wrong here. could someone help me with this. thanks.

Comment: Iam not a react person, but i think `RefObject` contains a property like `current` to access the dom element, so it should be `dialogRef.current.contains()`

Comment: thanks i missed it

Comment: So did adding `current` solve your issue here?

Comment: yes using current solved it

Answer (score 3):

You should assert `event.target` as `HTMLElement` or `HTMLDivElement`.
By the way, You can set event argument as `MouseEvent`.

**So, the right code is below:**

```
const handleClickOutsideDialog = (event: MouseEvent) => {
  if (
    dialogRef &&
    !dialogRef.contains(event.target as HTMLDivElement)
  ) {
    alert('You clicked outside of me!');
    setIsDialogOpen(false);
  }
};
```